# ArcGIS API for Silverlight : query that displays layer attributes in a dataGrid

Tags: layers, features, query, arcgis-silverlight-api

I'm working with ArcGIS API for Silverlight to build a webmapping application and I'm trying to display my attributes in a datagrid. I made a try by using this code :

```
void QueryTask_ExecuteCompleted(object sender,
         ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.QueryEventArgs args)
  {
   FeatureSet featureSet = args.FeatureSet;

  if (featureSet != null && featureSet.Features.Count > 0)
        QueryDetailsDataGrid.ItemsSource = featureSet.Features;
  else
        MessageBox.Show("No features returned from query");
  }

  private void QueryTask_Failed(object sender, TaskFailedEventArgs args)
  {
        MessageBox.Show("Query execute error: " + args.Error);
  }
```

But I get the result `No features returned from query`. I'm not sure, but it seems like the condition `featureSet != null && featureSet.Features.Count > 0`  isn't valid.